# How to get textbox values inside the table

Tags: c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table (with two textboxes Item and Count) in my webpage.

[image]

I try to access the values of two textboxes in each rows.

Please see my code below

```
 <table id="tbl-contents" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clsRow">
            <td>
                @*
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" data-required="true">*@
                <input id="txtItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="" data-required="true">
            </td>
            <td>
                @*
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Count" data-required="true">*@
                <input id="txtItemCount" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Count" type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="" data-required="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clsRow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Count">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="clsDelContent"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" style="font-size: 22px;"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clsRow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Count">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="clsDelContent"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" style="font-size: 22px;"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">
                <a class="clsAddContent"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="font-size: 22px;"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Script

```
        $('#tbl-contents tbody tr').each(function () {
            var customerId = $(this).find("td").html();



            alert(customerId);
        });
```

Comment: where's your script..? :\

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. please see my script above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.clsRow').each(function() {
    var foo = $(this).find('input');
    var item = foo[0].value;
    var itemcount = foo[1].value;
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9wv9/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('table  tbody tr td input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgLyb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script.

```
var reqValues = [];
$('.clsRow').each(function(i){
   var $currentTD = $(this).find('td')
   reqValues["item"+i] = $currentTD.eq(0).find('input').val();
   reqValues["values"+i] = $currentTD.eq(1).find('input').val();
 });
```

To get a particular value use the following code -

```
reqValues["item1"]
reqValues["values1"]
reqValues["item2"]
reqValues["values2"]
```